# AngularJS ng-if filter on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Can I make a NG-IF function in angular if the NG-IF is in a certain div ID?

I've got my application with tabs in the page, I'm loading the tabs with a NG-Repeat. And giving the certain div's different ID's, I can't put a variable in the NG-Model from the Div ID so I can't load out filtered data.

I have 8 Different groups, and in every group should be ONLY the filtered content.

If this is the array:

```
{
    "name": "Lucy",
    "gender": "Female",
    "hobby": "games",
},
{
    "name": "John",
    "gender": "Male",
    "hobby": "pets",
},
{
    "name": "Chris",
    "gender": "Male",
    "hobby": "music",
},
{
    "name": "Annie",
    "gender": "Female",
    "hobby": "sports",
},
```

And I want 4 different tabs with "hobbies"

"Games" "Pets" "Music" and "sports"

In the Games tab only Lucy should show up

In the Pets tab should only John show up

Etc

HTML Info:

```
            <div class="tab-pane"  id="groep{{item.Hobby}}"  ng-repeat="item in Hobbies">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="widget">
                                  <h4 class="widget-content-light">
                                    Hobbies: {{item.Hobby}}<br>
                                   </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="block-title">
                                    <h2><strong>Alle</strong> leerlingen</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="table-res">
                                    <table>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr ng-app="orderBy" >
                                                <th class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="">Hobby</a>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="item in Hobbies">
                                                <td class="text-center">{{item.Name}}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center">{{item.Hobby}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

There could be some typo's, but thats not the problem, i've recreated it fastly with different content.

Comment: Is there any way to know what the current tab is ?

Comment: What's your HTML structure ?

Comment: @Rebornix Yeah, every tab has a different ID,

Comment: @OmriAharon What would you like to know?

Comment: How it looks so we'll know how to fix your code.

Comment: If we know current shown tab, you can code as `<div ng-repeat="hobby in hobbies" ng-if='currentTabId === '' &&(hobby.id === 'Games' || hobby.id === "Pets")'`. You need to provide more info about whether it's possible.

Comment: I don't know about the others, but I still don't understand your problem. Maybe give us some more code, not just snippets. We don't know what `scope.hobbies` looks like, and what do the tabs look like. Where is the ng-model you have mentioned?!

Comment: @Rebornix i've added some code

Comment: please check the below code and let me know if that was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-show directive. I have created a fiddle where i have shown how can we control the display of a particular block with the help of ng-show.

Please check the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/eLodwebv/13/

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="selectedhobby">
        <option value="games">games</option>
        <option value="pets">pets</option>

    </select>
     <div class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="item in Hobbies" ng-show="selectedhobby == item.hobby">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="widget">
                                  <h4 class="widget-content-light">
                                    Name: {{item.name}}<br>
                                    Gender:{{item.gender}}
                                    Hobby:{{item.hobby}}
                                   </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>


</div>

var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
    $scope.Hobbies = [{
    "name": "Lucy",
    "gender": "Female",
    "hobby": "games",
},
{
    "name": "John",
    "gender": "Male",
    "hobby": "pets",
},
{
    "name": "Chris",
    "gender": "Male",
    "hobby": "music",
},
{
    "name": "Annie",
    "gender": "Female",
    "hobby": "sports",
}];

});
```